# VUE Need Pinia store info before mounted hook to retrieve from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, pinia

I am building a `VUE` application that uses `Pinia` as a store and `Firebase` as a database. I am trying to access a collection from `Firebase` on page load that requires me to have the **logged in users uid**.

Currently, I have stored the `user.uid` inside a **user** store created by `Pinia`.  The two hooks I have used are `setup` and `async created`. When running this, the error I get is that `this.authStore.user.uid` evaluates to **undefined**.

```
setup(){
    const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    return { authStore,db,};
  },
  
async created(){
    const q =  query(collection(this.db,this.authStore.user.uid)); //This does not exist
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      this.data[doc.id] = doc.data();
      // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });  
  },
```

I believe I need a method to delay the running of the function within `created`, however I am not sure how to wrap the whole code block in an `await` function to wait for the value `uid` to be available.

Comment: If you need this then don't mount a component until data is ready. There are several ways to do this, pick the one that fits your case, which is unknown. created is options api, you don't need to mix it with composition. You could use suspense but it's available in Vue 3 only, the question is incomplete

Comment: I am using Vue 3 Options API, the `setup()` hook if I remember right is to initialize `Pinia` store. I have tried to use `updated()`, `mounted()` and `beforeMount()` hooks but neither are working. Is there a hook that runs after the store is populated?

Comment: Use suspense. It's impossible to do this with a hook alone, apart from router hooks

Comment: Is it alright to use `suspense` which is an experimental feature? Also, is there another way to do this?

Comment: It's stable. Another way is to not render a component until data is ready in a parent, this is how this was done in Vue 2

Comment: Could you give me some insight on how to not render a component until data is ready? I will look to use `suspense` soon.

Comment: Call an action in a parent and use v-if to wait for it to compete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get it to work using `v-if` and `watch`. I added in a number that increments each time the page is loaded via the `mounted()` hook. I have a watcher that watches the number variable that triggers the **async function** to get data from `Firebase`.

```
data(){
    return {
        triggerWatcher:0
        }
},
mounted(){
    this.triggerWatcher += 1    
},
watch:{
    async triggerWatcher(){
        //async code that returns data from Firebase
        }
}
```

This seems to be quite stable for the time being; this solves the problem of not being able to call the `async doe that returns data from Firebase` in the `mounted, created, beforeMount` hooks as the **user.uid** needed to do that is not populated yet.

Comment: That's odd, I would expect onMounted to trigger once everything is ready. But this hack resolve a similar issue